# What is the name of this connector type?

Tags: connector

What is the name of this connector type? I have tried searching pretty much everywhere, but I can't find it. Please help.

[image]
[image]

Comment: amphenol connectors?

Comment: It may be what I know as an MS connector - Cannon makes them.  Any markings on the connectors?  A side view may also be helpful.

Comment: Looks like equidistant spacing. So that rules out DIN or XLR.

Comment: May be a LEMO connector.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Amphenol and MS connector leads me in the right direction. I can't get to the connector right now, but if I can't figure out the exact type, I will look closer, when I get a chance, and post some better pictures. Thanks again

Comment: Some Hirose connectors look like that... are there any markings on it? (other than the pin numbers.)

Comment: A side image and scale reference would help. Bayonet or threaded collar?
It might be MS3116f10-5s or a member of that series

Answer (score 2):

Generically, this is a 'circular connector'

This one might be (or compatible with) a MIL-DTL-38999 aka Amphenol circular connector. There are many variations- get out your calipers and hit the catalogs.